# Codaset, Codebasehq, Unfuddle, Trac or Redmine?

Tags: git, repository, trac, redmine

I have a handful of small Git repositories I would like to host remotely. They're all private projects, most of them in Java.

Codaset, Codebasehq, Unfuddle, Trac, Redmine..
There seems to be an abundance of solutions out there. They're all packed with features and useful functionality.

Putting aside pricing and the glossy layouts, what is the best way of comparing these options?

Comment: I did not know that something like Codaset existed. Thank you. :-)

Comment: You didn't specify what you actually what the front-ends for. For just hosting `git` already has a server, and `gitweb` or `cgit` are popular repository viewers.

Answer (score 2):

Up-front disclosure: I'm one of the Trac devs.

I think you need to look at what you're trying to accomplish, what functionality will help you accomplish those goals and how that matches up with the available options, and look at the flexibility the system provides.

I think flexibility is where Trac really shines -- [trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org) has a lot of plugins to add a lot of functionality (some better than others), and they aren't difficult to write; and the workflow is very configurable so it can match what you want your workflow to be.  You can make it very simple (a ticket is either open, or it's closed), or as complex as you can devise, with side-effects at certain transitions, etc.

You can also ask questions in #trac on freenode; it's pretty low noise, and there are generally a couple people around during US business hours who can answer questions and discuss Trac stuff with you.

To really compare the various options, I'd suggest setting up a small example project in each, play around with it, and ask questions.  But you really need to decide what matters to you to even get started.

Answer (score 2):

These pages might be helpful:

Wikipedia: [Comparison of project management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)

Wikipedia: [Comparison of issue-tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would suggest the same thing; give us all a go, and actual use each. That is the only way to really decide if it is what you need.

Comment: What do you do when you try solution A for project X, then decide that solution B is better? How will you transfer the project to a new project management solution? Most often you can't (working export / import is not common between PM solutions). So it's not that easy to "try" them on anything real.